# Combine two regular expressions in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with writting a reg exp for a string like this in C#

```
String correct = "<a>link</a>";
String wrong   = "link</a>";
```

I know how to select the first  in a reg exp example

```
string regExp = "^(<a>)";
```

Ans i know how to select the last one

```
string regExp = "(</a>)$";
```

But how could i combine this two, to one

Comment: Have you read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1283124)?

Comment: I only need it for anchor tags

Comment: Ilya, the answer that you proposed in the first comment is the best I ever read )) Bham, you need something like this: ^<a>.*?</a>$

Comment: If your using C#, have you tried using a DOM parser library instead of Regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<a>(.*)</a>");

string correct = "<a>link</a>";    
bool okBool = regex.IsMatch(correct); // true

string wrong = "link</a>";
bool wrongBool = regex.IsMatch(wrong); //false
```

Or as mentioned by [Ilya Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283124/ilya-ivanov), you can use this regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^<a>(.*)</a>$");
```

Comment: OP probably wanted something along `^<a>(.*)</a>$`

Comment: @Bham, I'm glad I could help! Please accept the answer, so the problem is marked as solved :)